# Redireccionar a una pagina con un boton jsx con react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

¿Cómo redireccionar un botón a otra pagina con `react`/`redux-form`, una vez se haya enviado los datos del registro? El código del botón es:

```
  <div className="btn-group">
    <Button
      type="submit"
      className="btn btn-primary boton"
      title="Crear"
      disabled={pristine || submitting}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola Jehyson, bienvenido a S.O.es. Creo que falta contexto en tu pregunta. ¿qué es lo que estás realizando actualmente al presionar el botón? ¿hay alguna función que estés llamando? Esa otra página donde quieres redirigir ¿la estás manejando con `react-router`? ¿existe la posibilidad de que redirijas desde el backend al recibir la información de tu form o necesitas que sea una redirección en el frontend?. Revisa [ask] para que veas como mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Hola Alter Lagos, estoy realizando un registro, no mayormente no estoy llamando ninguna función por ahora lo estaba intentando con react-router y no hallo como implementarlo, la pagina que quiero redirigir es a un listado, lo quiero redirigir desde el frontend, que una ves presione el botón de crear me redirija al listado para ver el registro. muchas gracias y quedo atento a tus comentarios.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta para incluir el código con el que ya intentaste hacer la llamada a la redirección con el router?